# Javascript: JSON.parse only if object exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some trouble with an if statement. I would like to parse JSON only if a certain cookie is found. Here's what I have:

```
var isCookie = if ($cookieStore.get('user') !== 'undefined') {
        JSON.parse($cookieStore.get('user'))
    } else {
        $cookieStore.get('user')
    };

var accessLevels = currentUser = isCookie || { access_token: '', role: userRoles.public, user_id: '' };
```

But I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if` error.

How can I parse my JSON only if the user cookie exists?

Comment: Try changing your if statement to if ($cookieStore.get('user'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var cookie = $cookieStore.get('user');
var isCookie = cookie ? JSON.parse(cookie) : cookie;
```

The only problem is that isCookie will be null if no cookie was found anyway.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is incorrect in the way you are declaring your if / else.   consider using a ternary operator in this case

```
var cookieStoreUser = $cookieStore.get('user');
var isCookie = cookieStoreUser ?  JSON.parse(cookieStoreUser) : cookieStoreUser;
```